# Is there any one done/implemented LTI tool with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lti, canvas-lms

I would like to build the LTI tool on Ruby On Rails platform where I found below library

https://github.com/instructure/ims-lti

I just want to know more ideas about it regarding ror platform If some one already done it/experienced.

Is there any one have idea about, To build LTI tool on ror?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Instructure provides an exemplary [tool provider](https://github.com/instructure/lti_tool_provider_example), as well as an exemplary [tool consumer](https://github.com/instructure/lti_tool_consumer_example), built on top of Sinatra.